# Remove a specific html jquery

Tags: jquery

I've done a search and haven't been able to work out from any specific examples on how to remove a specific html block from some content that doesn't have a specific CSS name added to it. It is part of a  list so the other elements can't be removed.

So I am trying to remove the content that is like this via Jquery:

```
<a class="header-block " href="/create">
  <span>
    <i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i><br />
  </span>
  Text 
</a>
```

I want to remove the entire code from the html. I have other A tags in there (as part of a UL that have `.header-block`), the only specific part is the `href="/create"` part.

Thank you :)

Comment: Your question is confusing, you say the HTML doesn't have a 'CSS name' to be able to select it, when it clearly has a class. Then you state you want to remove the entire block, which can be done with [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove). Then you say you only want to remove the `href` attribue, which can be done with [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr). I'd not suggest doing the latter though. Change `href` to `#` if you want to stop the link action.

Comment: Question is not confusing at all. He never stated that he wants to remove href attribute. Additionaly, he said that html block he wants to remove doesnt have any **specific** class to select it.

Comment: `the only specific part is the href="/create" part.`... It also seems the answers below are as confused as I am as they offer solutions which amend different parts of the HTML.

Comment: thats not class tho. I think he just didnt knew that he can make selector for href attribute.

Comment: HI guys, yeh I am very new to JS so I didn't know you could actually use a href as a selector.  My apologies if I wasn't clear enough as I was just reading it from my own view.  I wanted to remove the whole A tag but needed to leave the other tags, since I didn't know I could do this by the Href, I may not of been specific enough or even of needed to ask the question in the first place :).

Comment: The answers below definitely helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the block (`<a />` tag), you could do this with the `[href=""]` selector

```js
$('.header-block[href="/create"]').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <a class="header-block " href="/create">
    <span>
      <i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i><br />
    </span>
 Text 
 </a>
 <a class="header-block " href="/other">
    <span>
      <i class="fas fa-level-up-alt"></i><br />
    </span>
 Other
 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, if you have jQuery available:

```
$('a[href="/create"]').html('');
```

This removes all content within the `<a>` tag. 
If you want to remove the `<a>` tag as a whole, you can use `.remove()` instead of `.html('')`.